# Image resize in CSS working on Safari but not on Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to square photos with CSS (code below). For some reason, it won't work on Google Chrome (but it works on Safari). Does anyone know how to fix this?

CSS code:

```css
img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Result on Safari:

[image: link]

Result on Google Chrome:

[image: link]

Comment: What browser versions are you testing?

Comment: Please see [ask] and then provide a full example.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem but I've put a snippet in an 'answer' for you to try - let us know if you still have the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can put those images in a parent tag like `article` and then apply `width` & `height` to your parent tag(*article*). Then set the images *width* & *height* to 100% so the image fits the parent(article) completely.

This way: as you can see that the photo *width* is 500px but the parent doesn't let it Grow and occupy more space.

`https://picsum.photos/500` width: 500px.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}

article {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

article img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <article>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500">
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500">
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500">
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500">
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Does this work for images that aren't naturally square? I've seen some distortion on images with aspect ratios other than 1. The contain CSS setting seems to have been dropped.

Comment: Can you accept my answer? to accept my answer click on the check mark below the down vote. thanks

Comment: Hi, could you try it with non-square images first and check that you dont get disortion.

Comment: Yes, it does. There isn't any problem if the ratio is ``16:9`` or ``1:1``.

Comment: I tried it with https://picsum.photos/id/1049/200/300 and https://picsum.photos/id/1049/1024/768 and there is distortion (and that's not because lorem picsum has served them distorted, it just serves them appropriately cropped).

Answer (score 0):

No matter if your images ratio is `16:9` or `1`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container article {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container article img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<p> The width = 200 px and the height: 500 px</p>
<section class="container">
  <article>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/500">
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/500">
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/500">
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/500">
  </article>
</section><br>
<p>The same image you can see</p><br>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/500">
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this with the original image to test against. If you look you can see that the man is stretched horizontally.  And the slope on the mountain is different. There is distortion, the method does not work. It needs the object-fit (as in the question) to make sure it fits without stretching.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to the problem because I can't see that there is a problem but I thought it might be useful to put up a snippet which you can try on your version of Chrome to see if you are still experiencing the problem.

This snippet takes images, two of them square and one portrait and one landscape aspect ratio. As you can see they are cropped top and bottom or at the sides as appropriate to make them fit and cover the 300x300 squares. There is no distortion.

```css
img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1049/1024/768"/>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1049/768/768"/>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1049/768/1024"/>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1049/1024/1024"/>
```